# Calling methods from abstract class where concrete subclasses have different input parameters of those methods

Tags: java

Let's say I have this abstract class with its abstract method. 

Now this method is a very general concept that can differ a lot between implementations, not only in its body code but also in its input parameters. 
From what i understood if this is the case i shouldn't use an abstract method at all and let the concrete classes have their own version of the method, however I will later need an ArrayList of said abstract class that will contain different concrete classes and I want to call arraylist.get(i).method() without being concerned of which implementation this list cell points at.

What is the best way to solve this problem? Is there some handy pattern that fits my case?

Example of abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
    public abstract void act(){}
}
```

Example of concrete classes:

```
public class ConcreteOne extends AbstractClass{
     @Override
     public void act(int a){...}
}

public class ConcreteTwo extends AbstractClass{
     @Override
     public void act(char a){...}
}
```

Exemple of possible implementation:

```
private ArrayList<AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ConcreteOne());
list.add(new ConcreteTwo());
list.get(0).act(10);
list.get(1).act('a');
```

This obviously throws errors, so how do I fix it?

Comment: If you're going to call `arraylist.get(i).method()` what kind of parameters do those different method in those different classes require? You're certainly not passing them from this client code, so where would they come from? Can you please show some mock code in your question?

Comment: I provided a little example, hope it helps.

Comment: Those methods declared in your concrete classes do not actually override the method `act`(they would require the same parameters, but `act` doesn't have any), so that's one reason this would throw errors. You could try solving this problem by implementing generics so that each concrete class' `act` doesn't care what value goes in.

Comment: These are _overloads_, not _overrides_.  Overloads are methods with the same name but different parameter lists.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy Pattern may be the things that you want. Which help you change bussiness on runtime. But if you still want to play with this idea, you have to cast your object to child class before call overload method if your method not declare in parent abstract class.

```
public class RunApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ArrayList<AbstractClass> list = new ArrayList<AbstractClass>();
        list.add(new ConcreteOne());
        list.add(new ConcreteTwo());
        
        act(list.get(0), 1);
        act(list.get(1), "Hello");
        act(list.get(1), 100);
    }
    
    public static void act(AbstractClass subClass, Object param){
        if (subClass instanceof ConcreteOne) ((ConcreteOne) subClass).act(param);
        else ((ConcreteTwo) subClass).act(param);
    }

}

abstract class AbstractClass {
    public abstract void act(Object param);
}

class ConcreteOne extends AbstractClass {

    public void act(Integer param) {
        System.out.println("ConcreteOne act with Integer " + param);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(Object param) {
        if (param instanceof Integer)
            act((Integer) param);
    }
}

class ConcreteTwo extends AbstractClass {
    
    public void act(Integer param) {
        System.out.println("ConcreteTwo act with Integer " + param);
    }

    public void act(String param) {
        System.out.println("ConcreteTwo act with String " + param);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(Object param) {
        if (param instanceof Integer)
            act((Integer) param);
        if (param instanceof String)
            act((String) param);
    }
}
```

> ConcreteOne act with Integer 1
>
> ConcreteTwo act with String Hello
>
> ConcreteTwo act with Integer 100

Comment: I like the idea of casting but aren't all those if-else statements considered as a bad practice in java?

Comment: Also I thought about a strategy but I think I stumbled on the same problem, could you provide me with a little example on how to correctly use a strategy here?